# How to add shipping method in Google Pay Android

Tags: google-api, payment, braintree, android-pay, google-pay

[image]As per Gpay document I created Json request(gpay) for shipping method like:

```
 currencyCode: "USD",
    countryCode: "US",
    totalPriceStatus: "FINAL",
    totalPrice: "12.00",
    totalPriceLabel: "Total",
    checkoutOption: "DEFAULT",
    newShippingOptions: {
            defaultSelectedOptionId: "shipping-001",
      shippingOptions: [
        {
          "id": "shipping-001",
          "label": "Free: Standard shipping",
          "description": "Free Shipping delivered in 5 business days."
        }
      ]
    },
```

But I am getting developer error and not able to execute this Json request.
can anyone let me know, what am i doing wrong with this?

Comment: Is this for the Google Pay Online APIs? If so, are you able to provide a link to a reproduction scenario? JSFiddle works well.

Comment: This is all in API document:  https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects

Comment: @charisharma have you found any solution for this? I am getting same issue